# Disable IDF calculation

Tags: elasticsearch

In my particular use case, the IDF-factor that gets calculated as part of the TF-IDF algorithm messes up the scoring for my queries. Basically, I want the queries to only take the term frequency into account. Is it possible to disable the IDF factor, i.e set it to 1, for a particular index? I have looked into the similarity module (in version 0.90.X), but haven't really found anything that could help; same goes for the function_score query. Do I need to write a custom Similarity class in java? Or is there a plugin for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I believe it's connected with my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016735/elasticsearch-similary-for-countries, I tried to use DFR but with no success

Answer (score 1):

What about constant_score query?

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ignoring-tfidf.html

Don't hesitate to use ?explain=true to see how scoring is working.

As you can here without constant_filter:

[image: With IDF]

And with constant_filter query (that wraps your real query):

[image: Without IDF]

- Screenshots made with https://beemapp.me

Comment: Since "constant_score" does turn off both TF and IDF, I'm pretty sure that the result will be same with the result when use Filter. @GlurG seems like wanted to turn off only IDF while TF is turned on. Do you have any idea?

Comment: H, you mean change the scoring/ranking formulae? This page should help => https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html.