# Elasticsearch - similary for countries

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, similarity, relevance, scoring

I have a document, which contains many fields, one of them is `country`. There are many documents with the same `country`.

When I do `match query`, or `fuzzy` search against `country`, and query for `Belgium` for example, it returns list of documents, which matched `Belgium` country, but they all have different score. I believe it's because of tdidf similarity and presence of `belgium` term in other fields of documents, etc.

I'd like it return the same score in this case. What similarity should I use?

**Update**

I have next 6 documents:

```
{country:"Austria", title: "house"}
{country:"Austria", title: "Austria village"}
{country: "Germany", title: "deutch hotel" }
{country:"Austria", title: ""}
{country: "USA", title: "Usa hotel" }
{country: "USA", title: "Usa another hotel" }
```

When I execute match query against country:

```
{
   query: {match: {country: "Austria"}}
}
```

I reveice next results:

```
[ {
  "_index" : "elasticdemo_docs",
  "_type" : "doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {country:"Austria", title: "Austria village"}
}, {
  "_index" : "elasticdemo_docs",
  "_type" : "doc",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_score" : 0.30685282, "_source" : {country:"Austria", title: "house"}
}, {
  "_index" : "elasticdemo_docs",
  "_type" : "doc",
  "_id" : "3",
  "_score" : 0.30685282, "_source" : {country:"Austria", title: ""}
} ]
```

I'd like to receive the same `_score` for all 3 documents, because they all have `Austria` as a country. What similarity should I use?

Comment: What score value are you returning? Percentage, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a query instead of a filter? Filters won't affect scoring.

Comment: It's default score calculated by lucene.

I need to use query, because I'm using fuzzy search

Comment: Could you give 2-3 sample documents and a query like you write it?

Comment: Trying to generate, because on 2-3 documents:
{country:"Austria", title: "Austria village"}
{country:"Austria", title: "house"}
{country:"Austria", title: ""}
matching against country returns the same score, I believe it's connected with document structure and number of documents

Comment: I've updated original question with example

Answer (score 4):

Seems I found the problem - it's connected with:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch/

After using `dfs_query_then_fetch` search type I've got expected results.

Comment: +1, Thanks for following through and sharing what you've found.